# Why two local Maven repositories on Window 7?

Tags: maven

Without the complication of sharing all my `pom.xml`s, can you explain why I would have two local `Maven` repositories on Window 7 ? One is under `C:\Users\<my_user>\.m2\` and the other under `C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\`. The build takes place out of `Eclipse`.

Subsequently, I changed my `localRepository` in `settings.xml` to a custom directory and there has been no split download targeting since. I'm just trying to explain why it did before like it did.

Comment: local repo is not configured in your POMs. it is in settings.xml and defaults to .m2 under the invoking user. So you have been running maven as two different users.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do ith Eclipse.

It is because you have run `mvn` under each of those accounts at some time. If you create another account and run it under that new account you will get a third `.m2` directory. They are account specific. The paths show this explicitly.

Comment: sounds like a good hypothesis, however, I never logged in as Administrator, hence the mystery

Comment: Subsequently, I changed my `localRepository` in `settings.xml` to a custom directory and there has been no split download targeting since. I'm just trying to explain why it did before like it did.